# Why does .find() show fast MongoDB transaction times & slow node.js transaction times, and .findOne() shows the complete opposite?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I recently stress-tested my express server with the following two queries:

```
db.collection.find(queryCondition).limit(1).toArray()

// and

db.collection.findOne(queryCondition)
```

---

**[THESE ARE THE NEW RELIC RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPcd0.jpg)**

---

Can someone explain why `.find()` shows fast transaction times for `MongoDB` yet slow transaction times for `node.js`? Then, in complete contrast, `.findOne()` shows slow `MongoDB` times but fast `node.js` times?

For context, my express server is on a t2.micro instance and my database is on another t2.micro instance.

Comment: https://blog.serverdensity.com/checking-if-a-document-exists-mongodb-slow-findone-vs-find/

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7573/difference-between-mongodbs-find-and-findone-calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's compare the the performance of `.find()` and `.findOne()` in nodejs and on the mongodb level.

**MongoDb:**

Here, `find().limit()` should emrge as a clear winner as it fetches the [cursor](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Cursor.html) to the result, which is a pointer to the result of the query, instead of the data itself, and that is precisely the case as per your observation.

**Nodejs:**

Here, theoretically, `.find().limit()` should also emerge faster, however, it seems that in the New Relic results screenshot that you've linked, you're actually doing `.find().limit().toArray()` which fetches you an array of data as per your query instead of just fetching the cursor, and `findOne()` just fetches you a document (in the form of a JS object in nodejs).

As per the mongodb driver docs for nodejs, [`.find()` quickly returns a cursor and is, therefore, a synchronous operation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#find) that does not require a `.then()` or `await`, on the other hand, since [`.toArray()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Cursor.html#toArray) is a method of [`Cursor`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Cursor.html) and fetches all the documents matching the query in an array (not unlike fetching the cursor and putting all the documents that [`.next()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Cursor.html#next) can fetch in an array yourself). This can be time-consuming depending on the query, and therefore, it returns a promise.

In your test, what seems to be happening is that with `.findOne()`, you're fetching just one document (which is time consuming on the MongoDb level and at least as time consuming in nodejs as well) but with `find()`, you're first fetching the cursor (fast on the mongodb level) then telling the nodejs driver to fetch the data from that cursor (time consuming), which is why `.find().limit(1).toArray()` is appearing to be perhaps more time consuming than `findOne()` in nodejs, and in the bottom graph in your link, the space is almost entirely blue, which represents nodejs.

I suggest you try simply doing `.find().limit()` and checking the result, but then heed that you *won't* be getting your actual data, just a `cursor` that's pretty useless until you fetch data from it.

I hope this has been of use.

Comment: This is a great explanation. So, for my clarity, is ```.find().limit(1).toArray``` using my servers computational resources, and ```.findOne()``` using my databases? Would these two different queries determine which part of my service I need to vertically scale?

Comment: Pretty much. However, if I were you I'd choose not to neglect scaling in db if going with the `toArray` approach. The cursor will still have to consume some resources on the db level and frankly I'm a bit surprised that it's nodejs that hogs all the resources in that case. Perhaps it's something to do with how the nodejs driver for mongodb is implemented.